# Use hardware Trigger in Baumer neoAPI python SDK

Tags: python, opencv, baumer

I want to use Hardware Trigger in Baumer camera with neoAPI SDK. I found continuous mode in example but no documentation available for hardware trigger.

```
import neoapi
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

camera = neoapi.Cam()
camera.Connect('VCXU-51C')
camera.f.PixelFormat.SetString('RGB8')

for i in range(0, 200):
   frame = camera.GetImage().GetNPArray()
   frame = cv.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.2,fy=0.2, interpolation= cv.INTER_LINEAR)
   cv.imshow("window",frame)
   if cv.waitKey(1) == 27 :
      break
```

Comment: you should contact Baumer customer service.